# Is there a free way to send SMS via my app?

Tags: android, sms

I created an app and when some user Applies for some job ( that's what my application does ) I want that both of user the applier and the one who made the offer, automatically receive a SMS with both users informations.

It is necessary to implement some SMS gateway from other companies, where I have to pay for text messages? Or I can build it on my own?

Thank you!

Comment: you can't make force pay for user so your answer is No, but you can use push notification in free for them

Comment: I understand. This app is a delivery app and when some Sender Accept a job from a Carrier I want to send them a message with their phone numbers and emails to contact each other

Comment: so u can use api and server sms handler for it, first send a request from app to server and then send sms via backend process.

Comment: Instead of messaging, you can use something like Firebase Cloud Messaging and notify the users about the offer. Remember, this service is free to only some extent.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! Have a great day!

Comment: and one more thing, you can send email from app but at end point u need to give accept of user for confirm sending.use backend for sending email,it is free

Comment: I already implemented an email sender :)